# Android UI freeze while waiting for a http response

Tags: c#, android, http, xamarin

When i'm sending a http request with my app, the UI of my app freezes while i'm waiting for the http response.

Why is this happening?

```
async void HttpAction()
    {
        var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Timeout = 1500;

        await Task.Delay(500);

        using (HttpWebResponse reponse = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {

                if (reponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    //UI action
                    reponse.Close();
                }
    }
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Even though you use an `await Task.Delay(500);` (which is useless), the only important part of the code is synchronous. Stop using  `HttpWebResponse`/`HttpWebRequest` and start using `HttpClient` with `await HttpClient.GetAsync`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to await the `HttpAction` method at the calling point. Go through this [Async/Await article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) first for better understanding of Asynchronous programming.

There should not be any UI action inside Asynchronous Task rather return the result to the calling point and then perform the necessary actions.

```
async Task<bool> GetHttpAsyncStatus()
{
    var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.Timeout = 1500;

    using (HttpWebResponse reponse = await request.GetResponseAsync() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        if (reponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            // no UI Action, just return the result
            reponse.Close();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
     }
}
```

This must be invoked as

```
bool requestStatus = await GetHttpAsyncStatus();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `AsyncTask` and run your http calls in the doInBackground method. 
And inside the `onPostExecute` method, you update the ui. AsyncTask is not terribly involved and will free up the ui thread. I don't have much experience with async but AsyncTask and HttpurlConnection has never failed me on the more tricky stuff.

Comment: For why it's happening,  could the be another http call happening in the background still and they are overlapping?